# AVAudioPlayer eliminating one second pause between sound files

Tags: ios, ios5, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am using multiple instances of `AVAudioPlayer` to play multiple sound files in a succession.

I am noticing that there is a roughly one second pause when two different sound files are played. Is it possible to eliminate this one second pause? I call `[myPlayer prepareToPlay]` for each player ahead of time already.

Comment: do you get that same pausing when using the simulator vs device?

Comment: so far I've only tested on simulator, have not tried the device. Is this a known simulator issue?

Comment: no it was a long shot.  i have an android app with a similar problem but doesn't do it on the simulator due to extra processing power (meaning the delay or pause was caused from resources (or thread priority)), but apparently not :(

Comment: I see, in that case the lag on the actual device might be worse by the same token in my case. I'm wondering if there's a way to pause the whole sequence of files until they're all "loaded in" so to speak. I was thinking `prepareToPlay` would do that, but guess not. Can't say much about Android as I've never owned one (or developed for one) before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`AVAudioPlayer` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) you could use [`playAtTime:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW26) for synchronized playing.

Modified example would look like this:

```
- (void) startSynchronizedPlayback {

    NSTimeInterval shortStartDelay = 0.01;            // seconds
    NSTimeInterval now = player.deviceCurrentTime;

    [player       playAtTime: now + shortStartDelay];
    [secondPlayer playAtTime: now + shortStartDelay + player.duration];
}
```

I didn't test this but guess it should work. You should of course rename `player` and `secondPlayer` according to you names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not hearing the secondPlayer audio when I try this. The delegate method after completion (secondPlayer) gets called though, which is strange.

Comment: I got it to work, was using `CACurrentMediaTime()` instead of `deviceCurrentTime` and that made the difference. Not sure why though.

Comment: Sorry for late response but i see you got it working :) according to docs time has to be "greater than or equal to the value of the audio player’s deviceCurrentTime property" - this is probably where the problem was.

Comment: No prob, but now a separate issue came up with animation and sound synchronization (which is why I tried to use CACurrentMediaTime() to begin with, you can check the question out here if you have time  :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198893/reconciling-cacurrentmediatime-and-devicecurrenttime

Comment: Auch, i see the problem. It's a bit late for me (after >20 hours of work) but i marked your question for tomorrow - if you don't get a good answer till today.